# Angular Firebase Query Collection and Subcollection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

on my project I have a root collection called `stores`. Inside I have a *sub-collection* called `products`.

I'm trying to find a way to show all the products for a specific city (which is going to be in the `stores` collection. Basically, the idea is to find a cost effective way to query all the stores in "New York" and get all the products.

Is this possible? It's pretty much running a query after another and paying for 1 request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not offer any sort of join operation that lets you combine queries from multiple collections.

If you need to have a single query that gets everything, you will have to organize your data in such a way that supports the query you want to perform.

Comment: Hey! Really eh? :( That's a bummer... Thank you so much for your help thou.